# CSS LESSphp variable with CSS code block

Tags: css, less, lessphp

I would like to add multiple style declaration using lessphp. I have provide the $context array with the lessphp setVariables method.

```
$context['font'] = 'color: #ffffff; font-family: verdana;';
```

Then I would like to use it in the less file with the variable name, like this:

```
.selector{
  @font;
}
```

This doesn't work, what should be the appropriate way of handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two issues with what you are trying to do based on both LESSphp and LESS syntax:

1. The array from php needs to be [pairs of variable names and values](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#setting_variables_from_php), not property names and values.
2. LESS does not allow dynamic setting of property names.

So I believe a solution for you is something like this:

**PHP**

```
$context = array(
   "fontColor" => "#ffffff",
   "fontFamily" => "verdana"
);

$less->setVariables($context);
```

**LESS**

The above code should generate in the compiled LESS file the equivalent of this:

```
@fontColor: #ffffff;
@fontFamily: verdana;
```

Which then you use like this:

```
.selector {
   color: @fontColor;
   font-family: @fontFamily;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, but there is some cases when it could be a good thing to do what I wrote. (More freedom in PHP etc...) I have used a following hack:
$context['font'] = '";color: #ffffff; font-family: verdana;"';
Then is less: d: e(~"@{font}"); which produce the following: d:; color: #ffffff; font-family: verdana; As d is not valid CSS property browsers will skip and the others will work fine.

Comment: @RolandSoós If you are fine with such hacks, great. I try to avoid hacks so everything validates and I don't potentially run into unexpected behavior later. Glad you found something your are satisfied with.